# Error in intergrating EveryPlay in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, everyplay

after adding everyplay to my game , it gave me this string error

> PlayerSettings Validation: Requested build target group (25) doesn't exist; #define symbols for scripting won't be added.
>   UnityEditor.PlayerSettings:SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(BuildTargetGroup, String)
>   EveryplayPostprocessor:SetScriptingDefineSymbolForTarget(BuildTargetGroup, String, Boolean) (at Assets/Editor/Everyplay/Scripts/EveryplayPostprocessor.cs:754)
>   EveryplayPostprocessor:SetEveryplayEnabledForTarget(BuildTargetGroup, Boolean) (at Assets/Editor/Everyplay/Scripts/EveryplayPostprocessor.cs:700)
>   EveryplayPostprocessor:ValidateEveryplayState(EveryplaySettings) (at Assets/Editor/Everyplay/Scripts/EveryplayPostprocessor.cs:721)
>   EveryplayLegacyCleanup:Update() (at Assets/Editor/Everyplay/Scripts/EveryplayLegacyCleanup.cs:170)
>   UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

```
void Start()
{
    if (Everyplay.IsRecordingSupported())
        Everyplay.StartRecording();
    else
        Debug.Log("Not Supported!"); // it writes "Not Supported!" , then fire the error
}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Everyplay? That sort of error usually turns up when you're trying to use plugins that aren't compatible with Unity 5.

Comment: yup the latest version